# Dart Future and explicit resolve, reject

Tags: dart, promise, future

How can I explicitly resolve a future(or any other await-able type) in dart , just like javascript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Completer class : A way to produce Future objects and to complete them later with a value or error.